# Functions with real domain but complex range, do they have any use?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, soft-question

For example if we define the square root function like this:
$$\text{Sqrt}({x})= \begin{cases} 
\sqrt{x} &  x\geq 0 \\
i\sqrt{-x} & x<0
\end{cases}$$

Or we could have an exponential function with a negative base, which would be defined as:
$$(-a)^x=a^xe^{i\pi x}=(a^x\cos{\pi x})+i(a^x\sin{\pi x})$$

Notice that in both of these $x$ is real.

What I like about these functions is the fact that they can be easily visualized in 3D (1 for domain and 2 for range). Are functions like these (especially the second one) special in any way? Is there a name for these functions? Do they have a use?

I tried google, but I couldn't find anything (probably because I don't know what to call them), which is why I'm asking here. Also PLEASE don't attack me if my question seems stupid to you, because to me it is very genuine!

Comment: If you are defining $\sqrt x,$ then $\sqrt x$ shouldn't be in the definition.

Comment: In your first example, do you mean to define $\sqrt{x} = i \sqrt{|x|}$ for the case where $x < 0$?

Comment: @zhw. I saw your comment coming from a mile away haha, what should I use instead?

Comment: @mweiss , yes, just edited it, thank you!

Comment: In general the result of the Fourier transform is such a function. In fact, elements of the Fourier basis (i.e. complex sinusoids) are examples, as are certain wavelets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it is the standard. When a mathematician says $C[0,1]$ (read "the continuous functions on $[0,1]$) this is usually the set of functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb C$ that are continuous.

Comment: I disagree with that. If I see $C([0,1])$ with no further description, my default understanding is that this is the space of real continuous functions on $[0,1].$

Comment: I myself would vote on the side of Martin A., that in my experience the sanest default is that functions are complex-valued. One reason is that unitary operators are not diagonalizable on finite-dimensional spaces of real-valued functions... And characters of abelian groups really should be complex-valued, or else there'd be a lot of baggage about 2-D repns. Such stuff.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer.